# Timer for android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I wanna make an android app using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116903/i-wanna-make-an-android-app-using-eclipse)

I wanna make an android app using eclipse which will alert the user if the app has not been used for more than 3 days, do you think that is possible?

Its more like there is a timer inside the app which will display an alert to the user when the app has not been opened for 3 days or more.

I dont know how to do it, that is why im asking for help.

Comment: You would need to have a service running in the background all the time.

Comment: but how would i do it, or start it?

Comment: @m0skit0 no ... use AlarmManager(set + cancel) + Notification

Comment: [Exact Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11116903/940096)

Comment: @Selvin We came up with the same solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use `AlarmManager`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

It's "intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running."

You can `set` a notification in 3 days, but use the `cancel` method whenever the app is used.

Good luck.

Comment: is the code just a single line or like a whole class?

Comment: @Vintaga No, it's pretty short. Just get an instance of `AlarmManager`, using, as specified in the documentation,  `Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)`. Then make a notification `PendingIntent` thing: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html. Then set your manager, and, if the app is opened, cancel it by retrieving the `AlarmManager` again and using the `cancel` method.

Comment: See Arun George's answer for code.

Answer (score 1):

This code might help you:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourReceiverClass.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
    time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time.add(Calendar.SECOND, timeoutInSeconds);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```